# Android: Speech balloon - ImageView overlapping parent

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, parent

I'm trying to get an ImageView to overlap it's parent and create a speech balloon like, compound view. E.g:

[image: Speech balloon]

I am not able to have the triangle at the bottom be part of the blue block and overlap any other views/controls that are placed below it.

Does anyone have a way of doing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_content_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/background_green" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_down_arrow"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/triangle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="-25dp"
    android:background="@color/important_text_orange" />
</merge>
```

I thought the above XML was the way to go but it seems a negative margin or padding bottom is unable to push the view outside its parent.
**This XML is placed inside a relativelayout.**

Does anyone know the answer to this?

> **EDIT**
>
> My situation:
>
> [image]
>
> Is there any way to overlap the next elements padding without having
>   direct access to it?

Comment: Consider using a `RelativeLayout` I will quickly make an example xml file and post as answer. Then it will enable you to easily display Text on your speech bubble as well

Comment: I marked in bold that the merge is placed inside a relativelayout. The image is not mine and I used it as an example as to what I'm trying to create (Though my result is remarkably similar). I've got the text and image inside the square already (android:background="@color/background_green" is what i use to create the block). I just tried to push an imageview outside the parent. This is however not the best way?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer and the negative margin works. Feel free to check it out and let me know if that is what you wanted

Comment: @Orion why dont you just use a nine patch Drawable?

Comment: @Lunchbox Your answer is really nice but is not the answer I'm looking for. See my edit.

Comment: @pskink I've made the arrow a nine patch drawable already, though a drawable would not solve my current predicament. See my edit.

Comment: @Orion i think you have XY problem http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem

Comment: If you include the `complete_bubble` RelativeLayout below the content that you want it to display over, then it should work fine. Like the way I displayed it after the ImageView so that it could display correctly. You can just set the `layout_marginBottom` to change the amount to display over your other content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an xml file that creates something that could work. Try it out and let me know:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10sp" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/complete_bubble"
    android:background="#123456" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/complete_bubble"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-15sp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="10sp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_block"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:background="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This negative margin works.

Comment: Great answer it did work after correctly implementing this. Just out of curiosity, is there any other of doing this like whitout using layout_below etc?

Comment: In Relative layouts not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Using the image of the balloon as the background image of a `RelativeLayout` and then add a `TextView` to that layout.

Method 2 (Also the more awesome method): Creating a custom view that will not only draw the speech balloon but also have a `setText(String)` method that will adjust the text that is drawn in the bubble and resize it to fit the text always. Then you open source that and share with the world.

If you want to create a custom view...

```
public class AwesomeTextBalloon extends View {
    // constructors here

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // first draw the balloon
        // then draw the text
    }

    public void setText(String newText) {
        // set text variable here
    }
}
```

Then add the View programmatically or in the xml and call `setText()` to change the value of the balloon text.

Comment: your class AwesomeTextBalloon already. exists: its called TextView

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pop_up" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/header2"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="1dip"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_content_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_green"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appointment_ticket_signed_in_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroll"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/footer"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dip"
        android:src="@drawable/pop_dwn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```